# why request.getAttribute should be cast sometimes when using struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts

it is error:

```
<bean:define id="myid" value="<%=request.getAttribute("key")%>"
```

but followed with cast (String) is ok:

```
<bean:define id="myid" value="<%=(String)request.getAttribute("key")%>"
```

what's more. followed is ok.

```
this is <%=request.getAttribute("key")%>
```

why?

Answer (score 1):

`request.setAttribute("key","value as Object")` the value stored as `Object` (note big O) so when you retrieve back `request.getAttribute("key")` it returns as type Object so you need to caste it.

Answer (score 0):

[Example here](https://fenix-ashes.ist.utl.pt/open/trunk/fenix/src/main/webapp/projectsManagement/showTransferedOverheadsReport.jsp)

For `<bean:define/>` you are directly set the **Object** as value

i.e.

```
<%=request.getAttribute("key")%>
```

It always returns Object

So it is showing error.

You should cast it. Like

```
<%=(String)request.getAttribute("key")%>
```

**OR**

```
<%=request.getAttribute("key").toString()%>" />
```

[Struts bean Tag class](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/bean/define.html)

Comment: can you explain it in detailed? I can't catch your mean, 3ks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [< bean:define >](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/bean/define.html) docs:

- Specify a `name` attribute (plus optional property and scope attributes) - The created attribute and scripting variable will be of the type of the retrieved JavaBean property, unless it is a Java primitive type, in which case it will be wrapped in the appropriate wrapper class (i.e. int is wrapped by java.lang.Integer).
- Specify a `value` attribute - The created attribute and scripting variable will be of type `java.lang.String`, set to the value of this attribute.
- Specify nested body content - The created attribute and scripting variable will be of type `java.lang.String`, set to the value of the nested body content.

The [HttpServletRequest#getAttribute(String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) returns `Object`, while the `myId` will be `String`. This is why you have to do a cast.

In the meantime, the JSP fragment

```
this is <%= request.getAttribute("key") %>
```

will be completely valid because the `request.getAttribute(...)` will be evaluated and printed after the `this is` part. There's to need for casting here, because in this case the `Object#toString()` is invoked and the result is printed.

Comment: what about: jsp:param tag's value? is it should be casted?

Comment: find the documentation and check it :)